# Split string by brackets

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to split a string by brackets but my array has some extra empty values.

I tried using the code of a similar question that was answered and it splits the string but also adds empty values.

```
//  faq data
$faq                = "SELECT * FROM `web_content` WHERE catid = 13 AND `alias` = '".$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['alias'])."' AND state = 1 ORDER BY ordering";
$faqcon             = $conn->query($faq);
$faqcr              = array();
while ($faqcr[] = $faqcon->fetch_array());

$faqtext = $faqcr[0]['introtext'];
$arr = preg_split('/\h*[][]/', $faqtext, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output of the array is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

    [1] => Vraag1? || Antwoord1
    [2] => 

    [3] => Vraag2? || Antwoord2
    [4] => 

    [5] => Vraag3? || Antwoord3
    [6] => 
)
```

My string looks like this:

```
<p>[Vraag1? || Antwoord1]</p>
<p>[Vraag2? || Antwoord2]</p>
<p>[Vraag3? || Antwoord3]</p>
```

The `<p>` tags are irrelevant, im not splitting on those and I can just use strip tags afterwards.

Output of answer:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => [Vraag1? || Antwoord1]
                [1] => [Vraag2? || Antwoord2]
                [2] => [Vraag3? || Antwoord3]
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Vraag1? || Antwoord1
                [1] => Vraag2? || Antwoord2
                [2] => Vraag3? || Antwoord3
            )

    )
```

Comment: Looks like you just need `'/\s*[][]/'` to also match vertical whitespace (that is, if you strip the tags, and then you get an input string with linebreaks - see https://ideone.com/l542yN).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That still gives me empty array values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$line = '[This] is a [test] string, I think [this] answers [your] question.';
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $line, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: This gives me two arrays somehow, I'll add the output of your code in my question.

Comment: just use the second one i.e $matches[1]

Comment: just in case if you need array with brackets surrounded, you can use $matches[0]

Answer (score 1):

> Did you get the result you expected *(except for extra empty entries in the resulting Array)?*
> If your only Problem is just having empty Entries within your Array, you can quickly fix that with a combination of `array_values()` and `array_filter()` as demonstrated by the snippet below:

```
<?php

    $arr    = [
        '',
        'Vraag1? || Antwoord1',
        '',
        'Vraag2? || Antwoord2',
        '',
        'Vraag3? || Antwoord3',
        '',
    ];

    var_dump($arr);

    var_dump( array_values( array_filter($arr) ) );
```